# How to Evaluate two variables in robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework, evaluate

```
${req_attribute}=  Evaluate  ${result_attribute}.${tgt_record.TGT_ATTR_ID}
```

Comment: Please go over [Evaluate](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) and edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: Please take the time to create a complete [mcve]. What you're doing should work if the variables result in valid python.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in comment you can use `Evaluate` function to evaluate an expression. Expression must use Python syntax. Below is an example:

```
Evaluate an expression
    [Tags]    TestRail-C000000

    ${first_var} =    Evaluate  2
    ${second_var} =   Evaluate  3

    ${multiplication} =    Evaluate    ${first_var} * ${second_var}
    ${power} =    Evaluate    ${first_var} ** ${second_var}
    ${tuple} =    Evaluate    ${first_var}, ${second_var}

    Log To Console    ${multiplication}
    Log To Console    ${power}
    Log To Console    ${tuple}
```

Comment: Can I Evaluate like this?
${req_attribute}= Evaluate ${result_attribute},${tgt_record.TGT_ATTR_ID}
note- I changed comma instead of dot.

Comment: Yes, the result will be a `tuple`.  I'm updating the example to include this case.

Comment: Oh then how can I change that tuple into string?

Comment: You can use a formatted string: `${string} =    Evaluate    f"{${first_var}},{${second_var}}"`